# Not able to fetch current location in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to get the location while the task is running in the background.
When the app is running, the current location's lat and lng are fetched. But when the task is running in background the current location's lat and lng are not fetched.

```
      static Future<void> background() async {
    print("sendDataToGT60Device called");
    try {
      print("Entered the try block");
      
      //When the task is running in background I am not able to get the location.
      //But if the application is not removed from the background, the location is fetched properly.
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
      );

      print("got the location");

      double lat = position.latitude;
      double lng = position.longitude;

      print("$lat, $lng");
      double altitude = position.altitude;
      double speed = position.speed;

      double horizontalAccuracy = position.accuracy * 2;
      double hdop = horizontalAccuracy / 2;

      String serverAddress = getServerAddress();
      // var deviceInfo = await ImeiPlugin.getImei();
      // String imei = deviceInfo;


      // String? imei = await UniqueIdentifier.serial;

      print("****************imei $imei");

      DateTime now = DateTime.now();
      // int timestamp = now.toUtc();

      final url = Uri.parse(
          "http://$serverAddress/?id=$imei&lat=$lat&lon=$lng&timestamp=${now.toUtc().toString()}&hdop=$hdop&altitude=$altitude&speed=$speed");

      print("url $url");
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
      );

      print(response.body);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I have taken all the required permissions. But still getting the problem.

I am using this two packages

```
flutter_background_service: ^2.4.6
geolocator: ^9.0.2
```

Comment: For iOS, do you have this in your `Info.plist`?

`<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>`
`<string>This app needs access to location when in the background.</string>`

And for Android, do you have this in your Android Manifest?

`<uses-permission` `android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />`

Comment: @MatthewTrent Yes I have added both of them. Still I am facing same problem